# gcc distcc LTO cc invocations are not worth distributing

Tags: gcc, gnu-make, distcc

### env description

os: ubuntu 20.04
distcc: 3.4 (compiled from source) with method in below
common:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc make python3 python3-dev libiberty-dev autoconf -y
wget https://github.com/distcc/distcc/releases/download/v3.4/distcc-3.4.tar.gz -O /tmp/distcc.tar.gz
tar xvf /tmp/distcc.tar.gz -C /tmp/
cd /tmp/distcc-*; ./configure && make && sudo make install; sudo update-distcc-symlinks
```

build project:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3 -y
sudo apt-get install pkg-config -y
# for building all modules
sudo apt-get install build-essential gdb lcov pkg-config \
      libbz2-dev libffi-dev libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev \
      libncurses5-dev libreadline6-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev \
      lzma lzma-dev tk-dev uuid-dev zlib1g-dev -y
cd /tmp/
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.2/Python-3.11.2.tgz
tar xzf Python-3.11.2.tgz
cd Python-3.11.2
```

### problem description

I tried to build the project with below environments

```
export DISTCC_VERBOSE=1
export PATH=/usr/lib/distcc/:$PATH
export DISTCC_HOSTS="Test-7F-BR10-1-f1-1 Test-7F-SR4-11-14"
export DISTCC_POTENTIAL_HOSTS="Test-7F-BR10-1-f1-1 Test-7F-SR4-11-14"
```

I was expecting distcc will use remote servers to build but it failed to use localhost to build the code with below contents. I google a lot but haven't found useful info.

```
distcc[13888] (dcc_trace_version) distcc 3.4 aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu; built Mar 22 2023 13:43:26
distcc[13888] (dcc_recursion_safeguard) safeguard level=0
distcc[13888] (main) compiler name is "gcc"
distcc[13888] (dcc_set_path) setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
distcc[13888] (dcc_scan_args) scanning arguments: gcc
distcc[13888] (dcc_scan_args) LTO cc invocations are not worth distributing
distcc[13888] (dcc_get_hostlist) read hosts from environment
distcc[13888] (dcc_parse_hosts) found tcp token "Test-7F-BR10-1-f1-1"
distcc[13888] (dcc_parse_hosts) found tcp token "Test-7F-SR4-11-14"
distcc[13888] (dcc_lock_host) got cpu lock on localhost slot 0 as fd3
distcc[13888] exec on localhost: gcc -pthread -fno-semantic-interposition
```

What's more, the server side is ok. I ran below codes to start the server and i found the thread with commands `ps -ef --forest`

```
DISTCC_VERBOSE=1 distccd --jobs $(nproc) --log-stderr --no-detach --daemon --allow 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: There is no question in your post. This is a question and answer site. I do not understand, why do you write here? Yes, LTO is not really that much worth distributing. Do you want to know _why_ it is not worth distributing? What are you interested in?

Answer (score 1):

```
distcc[13888] (dcc_scan_args) LTO cc invocations are not worth distributing
```

The command that is invoked contains `-flto` which tells `gcc` to enable [link-time optimization](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), but In February 2021, the developers of `distcc` decided not to distribute the compilation when such an optimization is enabled (see [commit](https://github.com/distcc/distcc/commit/8dacd28d888210753e9457eb31175d8e2a1c348e)).

It's likely that you are trying to compile all the source files using the same options, which includes `-flto`, so none of the compilation is distributed, and everything is done on your local machine.

Note that this seems to have been reverted in July 2021 in [this commit](https://github.com/distcc/distcc/commit/b94b751aef444e0e9e5224730891650d03d12a4d), but the latest release was [cut in May 2021](https://github.com/distcc/distcc/releases/tag/v3.4).

In short, either:

- disable link-time optimization
- build `distcc` from the last commit of master